# turnkey solution for engaging website visitors with embedded live stream, with call to action and/or chat

Tags: user-engagement, streaming, chat, live

I need a turnkey solution for a live stream with call to action and/or chat on one page of our wordpress site, which meets the following requirements:

1. I want all visitors to the webpage to instantly see and hear us speaking to them immediately upon landing on the page. And I want it work on all devices. And no plugins, no need to click anything or "allow" anything.  In other words, I need a responsive embedded HTML5 live stream that loads instantly and allows the visitor to see us and hear us without having to click or "allow" anything.
2. I want to know when a visitor lands on the page so that we can address them live.
3. I want to be able to engage the visitor with a call to action.  Perhaps even allow them to type to us.  But at least be able to display a call to action button.  Ideally a chat option too, which does not require any sign in or anything to "allow".

So in short, I need a responsive embedded HTML5 video stream, with call to action and/or chat to be able to engage each visitor as they land on the page.  The visitor should not be required to click anything or "allow" anything in order to see us and hear us (nor should they be required to sign in to anything or "allow" anything to be able to chat with us if there is a chat option).

I've searched a lot for solutions such as web conferencing, webinars, live chat support, youtube live, etc., but I haven't found anything that meets our requirements.  Anyone know a turnkey solution for what we need?  Where we just configure it and then add the embed code to the webpage?  Thanks in advance!